# How to control the GPS event after the app killed from the task management bar?

Tags: iphone, gps, notifications

Please see following url..

http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/12/introducing-google-latitude-app-for.html?m=1

I don't know how it's doing this, but this app will continue to use the GPS even after it's killed from the task management bar.

The only way to stop it from using the GPS is to rerun the app and disable background updating. That or disallow Latitude from the Location Services settings.

It doesn't seem to drain the battery like other GPS apps though, so my guess is it's using triangulation. That or it's not polling that frequently.

How can I do that?

Please help me..

Comment: It seems to use the 'significantLocationChange' setting.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably using the region monitoring apis. This allows for location monitoring without actively using your GPS. It grabs location based on wifi and cell triangulation combined with the normal phone activity. It makes this location information public to other apps to use. (location information is stored at OS level, not app to app sharing).

The only way to disable location monitoring is to revoke the apps rights to location services. So if you keep the app around, there isn't much you are going to be able to do. But know that the hit to your battery should be minimal.

Comment: Dear,Bill.

I want to make reminder app for time-based,location-based reminders.

I implemented time-based function easily by using Local Notification.

The app should get current location frequently and calc distance between to reminders .

If the reminder is in the special area,then local notification message should show.

I didn't complete location-based yet.

Because,it should work even when the app is in background mode or is closed..

How can I  get current location and calc distance when the app is closed?

If you have,would you send sample code?

Best Regards/

Comment: The new Notifications app that Apple is releasing with iOS 5 is making good use of the region monitoring. This is available on the iPhone 4 and up. If you want to target older devices, you have to get a bit more creative and use the other location tools available. Good luck.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make the same app Apple plans to bundle with iOS 5. I would research their app first, as they have a long history of not approving apps that offer the same functionality as their own. It would also save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Thanks,Bill

I will remember that you're really good friend.

This app will use on the iPhone 4 and up.,
So it doesn't target older devices.

I;m very interested that  Apple is planning to make same app that I 'm developing now.

Can I use the functionality of apple,so that I can save time and effort?

If I can use,where I can find it?

Very Very Thanks.

Best regards.